# How to fix "could not find 'init(domain:code:userInfo:)' in parent class" while archiving?

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm doing a Swift migration for my existing project from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2. I've already executed the Xcode 10.1 Assistant, and my project compile correctly in debug, but when I try to archive it gives me the error from the Title.

My project consists of

- Main Project -> Migrated to Swift 4.2
- Utilities Pod -> Swift 3.2

In the Utilities Pod, there's a NSError subclass (CMError)

```
public class CMError: NSError {

    // MARK: - Initializers

    public convenience init(type: CMErrorType) {
        self.init(domain: CMErrorDomain,
                  code: type.rawValue,
                  userInfo: type.localizedUserInfo())
    }

    public convenience init(type: CMErrorType, code: String) {
        self.init(domain: CMErrorDomain,
                  code: type.rawValue,
                  userInfo: type.localizedUserInfo(code: code))
    }

    public convenience init(type: CMErrorType, code: String, localizedDescription: String) {
        self.init(domain: CMErrorDomain,
                  code: type.rawValue,
                  userInfo: type.localizedUserInfo(code: code,
                                                   localizedDescription: localizedDescription))
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive when archiving.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone figure out what can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to update the pod to a version which supports your swift version

Comment: @Scriptable already tried that and still the error appears

Comment: `domain: CMErrorDomain` doesn't make any sense. You need to pass a domain instance not the type

Comment: @LeoDabus CMErrorDomain is a String.
let CMErrorDomain = "CMErrorDomain"

Comment: If it is a var it should be lowercased

Comment: Have you tried to call `super.init(domain:code:userInfo:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've added an override of the NSError init in my CMError subclass, and it archived successfully.

```
public override init(domain: String, code: Int, userInfo dict: [String : Any]? = nil) {
    super.init(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: dict)
}
```